# parse error on input 'else' on an If-Then-Let-Else statement (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

This portion of code checks if a number given (First element in a list) is zero 
(yes i tried == 0 but got other errors) 
It then return all elements of another list except the first one. 
If not, it returns another list.
The function is of type [a] and 'newpack' needs to be a variable as it is used later.

```
                              if ((position!!1) < 1)
                                then 
                                    let newpack =   drop ((length pack)-1) pack
                                else
                                    let newpack = (take ((position!!1)-1) pack) ++ (drop ((position!!1)+1) pack)
```

error is 46:73: parse error on input `else'

Do have any idea why this is not working? Is it that'let's needs an 'in' with them?

Thanks for your help,

J

Comment: Note: `position !! 1` yields the second element of the list `position` (or a runtime error, if it is too short). Indices are 0-based.

Comment: If you come from a C-style language, just train yourself to exchange every Haskell `if a then b else c` with `a? b : c` in your mind. What imperative languages call `if` is `when` in Haskell (not available by default, you have to import `Control.Monad`), but you can't use that in this way either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `in` part is not optional. You can write this as:

```
let newpack = if (position !! 1) < 1
                then drop ((length pack)-1) pack
                else (take ((position!!1)-1) pack) ++ (drop ((position!!1)+1) pack)
in ...rest of code...
```

If you're in a do block, then you can omit `in` onwards, but either way, you can't put the conditional outside the binding.

(If you're hoping to modify `newpack` as if it was a mutable variable, that's just not possible; all `let` does is give a *name* to a value, you can't actually modify anything. But how to structure your code without this would be beyond the scope of this question; if you need help with that, you should ask another.)

Some stylistic notes:

- Explicit list indexing is generally considered a bad idea; depending on what it's used for, you might want to consider making `position` a tuple or some other data structure.
- Similarly, `length` is probably a bad idea too (it has to traverse the entire list just to give a result).
- You have a lot of redundant parentheses: `drop ((length pack)-1)` can be simply `drop (length pack - 1)`.

A nicer way to write this (from a purely aesthetic point of view — i.e. ignoring the list indexing and use of `length`) would be (using [guards](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards)):

```
let firstPos = position !! 1
    newPack
      | firstPos == 0 = drop (length pack - 1) pack
      | otherwise     = take (firstPos - 1) pack ++ drop (firstPos + 1) pack
in ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it seems like an intelligent solution and bonus for stylistic notes. I seem to have problems with guards (I am using Kate program on Linux OS) giving me a 45:65: parse error on input `|'

Comment: You might be indenting your code with tabs. Make sure there are only spaces in your file, no tabs; if there are tabs, look up how to set your editor to expand them to spaces. (Basically, Haskell interprets tabs as 8 spaces, which means that if your editor shows them as smaller than that, things can look lined up to your editor but totally wrong to Haskell.)

Comment: I enabled this feature on Kate, fiddled with the code and it works exactly how i want it to now. @daniel-fischer this was also a useful piece of information that i overlooked (the position!!0). Cheers guys.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it that 'let's needs an 'in' with them?

Yes. (`do`-blocks are a special case; however, even in a `do`-block, the rest of the block is a bit like being in an implicit `in`.) You might consider writing something like this:

```
let newpack = if {- ... -} then {- ... -} else {- ... -} in
{- the rest of your computation that uses newpack -}
```